# inflection points of a projective conic

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $C=\{x=(x_{0},x_{1},x_{2}) \in \mathbb{P}^{2}| f(x)=x_{1}^{2}-x_{0}x_{2}=0\}$. I want to find inflection points of $C$. So, I need to find $P \in C \subset \mathbb{P}^2: H(f)(P)=0$, where $H_{ij}(f)=(\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x_{i} \partial x_{j}})$ and $H(f)=\det H_{ij}(f)$.

The Hessian matrix:
$$ H_{ij} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Then $\det H_{ij}=-2$. What is wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So there is no inflection point on a conic.

Comment: @ AG learner Does it mean that all non-degenerate conics have no inflection points?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong here. An inflection point $p$ on a curve $C$ is a nonsingular point where the tangent line to $p$ meets $C$ with multiplicity at least three. By Bezout, the sum of the intersection multiplicities of a conic and a line in $\Bbb P^2$ is two, so no conic in $\Bbb P^2$ can have an inflection point.